# get data from JSON Object according to a key

Tags: javascript, html

I have this JSON Object.

```
{ 
  "headerContent": [
    {
      "name": "User Id",
      "key": "userId",
      "type": "text",
      "default": "Enter User Id"
    },
    {
      "name": "User Name",
      "key": "userName",
      "type": "text",
      "default": "Enter User Name"
    },
    {
      "name": "Password",
      "key": "password",
      "type": "password",
      "default": "Enter Password"
    },
    {
      "name": "Mobile Number",
      "key": "mobileNumber",
      "type": "text",
      "default": "Enter Mobile Number"
    },
    {
      "name": "User Category",
      "key": "userCategory",
      "type": "select",
      "default": "Select Category",
      "options" : ["Admin", "Client", "Regulator"]
    },
    {
      "name": "E-Mail",
      "key": "email",
      "type": "text",
      "default": "Enter Email"
    },
    {
      "name": "User Access",
      "key": "userAccess",
      "type": "select",
      "default": "Select User Access",
      "options" : ["All", "Site"]
    }
  ],
  "bodyContent": [
    {
      "userId": "user_1",
      "userName": "DemoUser",
      "mobileNumber": "99999999",
      "userCategory" : "Admin",
      "email" : "demo@kl.com",
      "userAccess" : "All"
    }
  ]
}
```

The `headerContent` describes the attributes of `bodyContent`.
Now, by default all data in the object (like user_1) will be displayed in `details`. In the html page I have a select box containing 3 values [Admin, Client, Regulator]; which are 3 different user category. When I select any of them, I want to display data based on the selection.

My HTML page contains a select box to select the category.

```
 <script src="JSCode.js"></script>
 <select id='listSelect' onChange="updateList()">
    <option value='' selected >All</option> 
    <option value='admin'>Admin</option>
    <option value='client'>Client</option>
    <option value='regulator'>Regulator</option>
</select>
<div id='details'> </div>
```

Comment: Post html and also mention things you have tried.

Comment: **When I select any of them, I want to display data with userCatagory="Admin".** where's the data for Admin category ?

Comment: in the `headerContent` check 5th data (attribute).

Comment: @Coder007 have posted my answer.

Comment: I'm sorry ... I think I am not alone with my problem. I don't see ANY data related to usercategory = "Admin" .... the 5th array index element describes some select options, but no data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**JSFiddle** [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7h8mt44m/)

**HTML**

```
<table align='center' >
    <tr>
        <td> <select id='listSelect' onChange="updateList()">
            <option value='' selected >All</option> 
            <option value='Admin'>Admin</option>
            <option value='Client'>Client</option>
            <option value='Regulator'>Regulator</option>
        </select></td>
   </tr>
</table>
<div id="result"></div>
```

**JS**

```
var jsonObj = { 
  "headerContent": [
    {
      "...": "..."
    }
  ],
  "bodyContent": [
    {
      "userId": "user_1",
      "userName": "DemoUser",
      "mobileNumber": "99999999",
      "userCategory" : "Admin",
      "email" : "demo@kl.com",
      "userAccess" : "All"
    },
    {
      "userId": "user_2",
      "userName": "DemoUser",
      "mobileNumber": "99999999",
      "userCategory" : "Client",
      "email" : "demo@kl.com",
      "userAccess" : "All"
    }
  ]
};

function searchJSON (json, content, where, is) {
    content = json[content];
    var result = [];
    for (var key in content) {
        if (content[key][where] == is || is == '') {
            result.push(content[key]);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

function printObj (obj, container) {
    var html = '<table>';
    for (var i in obj) {
        for (var j in obj[i]) {
            html += '<tr><td>' + j + '</td><td>' + obj[i][j] + '</td></tr>';
        }
        html += '<tr><td class="black"></td><td class="black"></td></tr>';
    }
    document.getElementById(container).innerHTML = html;
}

function updateList () {
    var e = document.getElementById("listSelect");
    var value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    printObj(searchJSON(jsonObj, 'bodyContent', 'userCategory', value), 'result');
}

updateList();
```

On change it executes `updateList()`. This function gets the value of the element. Then it executes `searchJSON()`. This function needs the data (`jsonObj`), the content in your data (in your case `bodyContent`), the key you are looking for (in your case `userCategory`) and the value you are looking for. The function loops through the data object and searches for the key. If the value is the same as your select, it adds the object to an array. When the loop is complete it returns the result.

Last function is a simple print function to place the data inside your html. To make sure it gets printed first time, just run the `updateList()` once.

**LOADING .JSON** [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567114/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-without-jquery)

```
var xmlhttp;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
    // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE ) {
       if(xmlhttp.status == 200){
           jsonObj = xmlhttp.responseText;
       }
       else if(xmlhttp.status == 400) {
          alert('There was an error 400')
       }
       else {
           alert('something else other than 200 was returned')
       }
    }
}

xmlhttp.open("GET", "jsonInfo.json", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: bt. I have a little problem. The JSON data are stored in a `jsonInfo.json` file. So, first I have to assign the contents of this file to a json object. Like `var jsonObj = content('jsonInfo.json');`

Comment: Take a look at: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567114/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-without-jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567114/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-without-jquery) You can use an AJAX call to read the file. Making an edit in my post. Can't test it atm, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way..

```
var data;
for (var key in data) {
   var value = data[key];
   alert(key + ", " + value);
}
```

Comment: actually, I want display data objects in the json object named `bodyContent`. If the select box have the value `All` , list all data in it. If select box have the value `Admin`, list the data in `bodyContent` object where `userCategory`=`Admin`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```js
var data = { 
  "headerContent": [
    {
      "name": "User Id",
      "key": "userId",
      "type": "text",
      "default": "Enter User Id"
    },
    {
      "name": "User Name",
      "key": "userName",
      "type": "text",
      "default": "Enter User Name"
    },
    {
      "name": "Password",
      "key": "password",
      "type": "password",
      "default": "Enter Password"
    },
    {
      "name": "Mobile Number",
      "key": "mobileNumber",
      "type": "text",
      "default": "Enter Mobile Number"
    },
    {
      "name": "User Category",
      "key": "userCategory",
      "type": "select",
      "default": "Select Category",
      "options" : ["Admin", "Client", "Regulator"]
    },
    {
      "name": "E-Mail",
      "key": "email",
      "type": "text",
      "default": "Enter Email"
    },
    {
      "name": "User Access",
      "key": "userAccess",
      "type": "select",
      "default": "Select User Access",
      "options" : ["All", "Site"]
    }
  ],
  "bodyContent": [
    {
      "userId": "user_1",
      "userName": "DemoUser",
      "mobileNumber": "99999999",
      "userCategory" : "Admin",
      "email" : "demo@kl.com",
      "userAccess" : "All"
    }
  ]
}

$("#listSelect").change(function(){
var opt = $(this).val();
    console.log(opt);
    $.each(data.headerContent,function(i,v){
        if(v.hasOwnProperty("options"))
        {
           var index = -1;
            v.options.some(function(element, i) {
                if (opt === element.toLowerCase()) {
                    index = i;
                    return true;
                }
            });
           if(index != -1)
           {
               $("#details").text(v.name + " " + v.key);
           }
           
           
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table align='center'>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select id='listSelect' onChange="">
                <option value='' selected>All</option>
                <option value='admin'>Admin</option>
                <option value='client'>Client</option>
                <option value='regulator'>Regulator</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p id='details'>
            </P>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @Coder007 What's not happening ? its showing here, just run this code snippet.

Comment: its printing `User Category userCategory` for all selection